# How to store the value of a recursive function in a list in prolog?

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

My assignment is:

> Given the following definition of function f, create a Prolog program to compute f(i) for all 0 < i < 32.
>
> - f(0) = 0
> - f(1) = 1
> - f(n) = f(n-2) + 2*f(n-1) for n > 1

My code so far is:

```
problemThree(0, 0).
problemThree(1, 1).
problemThree(N, NF) :-
    N > 1,
    A is N - 2,
    B is N - 1,
    problemThree(A, AF),
    problemThree(B, BF),
    NF is AF + 2*BF.
```

It is working but it is taking forever to show the values for N > 20.

Please let me know how do I store the values in a list to make the program faster.

Comment: The reason the performance 'blooms' is because the time required is exponential per the value `n` since you are recursing deeply twice for each computation. @repeat shows the solution which resolves this problem by keeping the last couple of computed values so they do not need to be recomputed. It's a common technique in a recursive Fibonacci-like computation.

Comment: @lurker. It's about time we solve the "linear recurrence" problem class in Prolog once and for all:)

Comment: thanks a lot for your response

Answer (score 5):

Here's a DCG approach which generates the sequence as a list:

```
prob3(1, F0, F1) --> [F0, F1].
prob3(N, F0, F1) --> {N > 1, F2 is 2*F1 + F0, N1 is N-1}, [F0], prob3(N1, F1, F2).

prob3(0, [0]).
prob3(N, FS) :-
    phrase(prob3(N, 0, 1), FS).

?- prob3(10, L).
L = [0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, 169, 408, 985] ;
false.

?- prob3(169, L).
L = [1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, 169, 408, 985, 2378, 5741, 13860, 33461, 80782, 195025,
..., 17280083176824678419775054525017769508908307965108250063833395641] ;
false

?- time((prob3(1000, L),false)).
% 3,011 inferences, 0.005 CPU in 0.005 seconds (100% CPU, 628956 Lips)
false.
```

---

Note that for long list answers, SWI Prolog will abbreviate the output, such as:

```
?- prob3(20, L).
L = [0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, 169, 408|...]
```

This is just SWI Prolog's way of not cluttering the screen with lots of output. Here, you can respond with `w` and it will give the entire result:

```
?- prob3(20, L).
L = [0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, 169, 408|...] [write]   % PRESSED 'w' here
L = [0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, 169, 408, 985, 2378, 5741, 13860, 33461, 80782, 195025, 470832, 1136689, 2744210, 6625109, 15994428] ;
false

?-
```

See, [Help: I want the whole answer](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html).

Comment: I am only getting 9 values after which it just shows a vertical bar and stops something like this: ?- prob3(20, L).   L = [0, 1, 2, 5, 12, 29, 70, 169, 408, |....

Comment: @user197618 That's SWI Prolog's abbreviation for output to display. When you get the prompt, press `w` (instead of the semlicolon, `;`). See, [Help: I want the whole answer](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html).

Answer (score 2):

No need to store more than the previous two numbers!

Here's my quick-and-dirty shot from the hip:

```
p3(N,F) :- 
   (  N =:= 0 -> F = 0
   ;  N =:= 1 -> F = 1
   ;  N  >  1 -> N0 is N-2, p3_(N0,0,1,F)
   ).

p3_(N,F0,F1,F) :- 
   F2 is F0 + 2*F1,
   (  N =:= 0
   -> F2 = F
   ;  N0 is N-1,
      p3_(N0,F1,F2,F)
   ).
```

Sample query:

```
?- between(25,35,N), p3(N,F).
  N = 25, F = 1311738121
; N = 26, F = 3166815962
; N = 27, F = 7645370045
; N = 28, F = 18457556052
; N = 29, F = 44560482149
; N = 30, F = 107578520350
; N = 31, F = 259717522849
; N = 32, F = 627013566048
; N = 33, F = 1513744654945
; N = 34, F = 3654502875938
; N = 35, F = 8822750406821.
```

Something *a little* bigger:

```
?- p3(111,F).
F = 1087817594842494380941469835430214208491185.

?- p3(123,F).
F = 42644625325266431622582204734101084193553730205.

?- p3(169,F).
F = 17280083176824678419775054525017769508908307965108250063833395641.
```

Fast enough?

```
?- time((between(0,1000,N), p3(N,_), false)).
% 2,006,005 inferences, 0.265 CPU in 0.265 seconds (100% CPU, 7570157 Lips)
false.
```

Answer (score 2):

Though it's much slower than other answers, I like this one with a functionnal spirit :

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

f(N, FN) :-
    cont_f(N, _, FN, \_^Y^_^U^(U = Y)).

cont_f(N, FN1, FN, Pred) :-
    (   N < 2 ->
        call(Pred, 0, 1, FN1, FN)
    ;
        N1 is N - 1,
        P = \X^Y^Y^U^(U is X + 2*Y),
        cont_f(N1, FNA, FNB, P),
        call(Pred, FNA, FNB, FN1, FN)
    ).
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: Use a variable `Pred_3`, if 3 arguments are missing. This `call(Pred_3, A,B, C)` is valid.

Comment: @false I'm sorry, I don't get what you intend to mean :(

Comment: You could add more information to your program by using a special naming convention for meta-arguments.  For goals, that can be called directly, you can say `Goal_0`, thus `call(Goal_0)`. For goals that lack one argument say `Goal_1` which will be called as `call(Goal_1, X)`. And in your case the variable `P` could be `P_4`, just as `Pred_4` could.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. I thought that I had missed something in my code.

Answer (score 1):

memoizing is useful, I used it for speedup primes computing with the Erathostenes sieve

```
?- time((between(0,1000,N), prob3(N,_), false)).
% 10,939 inferences, 0.011 CPU in 0.012 seconds (99% CPU, 951780 Lips)

:- dynamic memo/2.
prob3(0, 0).
prob3(1, 1).
prob3(N, R) :- memo(N, R), !.
prob3(N, R) :-
    N > 1, N2 is N-2, N1 is N-1, prob3(N2,R2), prob3(N1,R1), R is R2+2*R1, assertz(memo(N, R)).
```

Comment: s(X). Memoizing unary functions should definitely be a common Prolog idiom! Something that allows imposing resources limit (using some LRU-based replacement scheme). What would be a good API for that?

Comment: hey, thanks a lot for your response I tried using it but I get an error: ERROR: prob3/2: Undefined procedure: memo/2
   Exception: (8) memo(25, _G977) ?

Comment: you need the declaration `:- dynamic memo/2.`